# meteor why redundant port and host in meteor build command?

Tags: meteor

Say, I want to deploy meteor app `foo` to `http://example.com:3000` on my own server. I found `--server` doesnot matter. Whether:

```
meteor build /root/deploy/foo --server http://example:3000
```

or

```
meteor build /root/deploy/foo
```

You can both get app run with:

```
env PORT=3880 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp ROOT_URL=http://example.com node main.js
```

Note I change port to 3880. So my question is:

1. As you can change port when you start a meteor server even if you specify --server when building app, what's the meaning of `--server`?
2. As you already specify host and port in `--server` why shoud I provide `PORT` and `ROOT_URL` again when start server?